# Render field form type twig symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I would like to duplicate the same field several times with different values ​​in the drop-down list in twig. I add a simple form with a TextType, but in twig in a for loop, the rendering of the field is done only once. How can I make this system under symfony ? ( In a for loop )

[image]

Comment: Could you @OcB974 please accept my answer if you think it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution. Thank you. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

When you try to create a form in your controller and then you render it to you'r view , it gonna be one and only one form , you can't duplicated with a loop because at the end, it gonna give you 2 forms with the same <kbd>form_id</kbd>  , so if you need 2 forms you need to instantiate them with your builder the same thing with you'r fileds.
*Take a look:*

```
$task1 = new Task();
$task2 = new Task();

$form1 = $this->createFormBuilder($task1)
            ->add('task', TextType::class)->add('task2', TextType::class);

$form2 = $this->createFormBuilder($task2)
            ->add('task', TextType::class);
```

And about the drop down , you need to create a form with ChoiceType Field :

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

$builder->add('Tasks', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => array('task1','task2','task3));
```

Answer (score 0):

`CollectionType` field type is used to render a "collection" of some field or form. In the easiest sense, it could be an array of TextType fields that populate an array values.

Example:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
// ...

$builder->add('emails', CollectionType::class, [
    // each entry in the array will be an "email" field
    'entry_type' => EmailType::class,
    // these options are passed to each "email" type
    'entry_options' => [
        'attr' => ['class' => 'email-box'],
    ],
]);
```

The simplest way to render this is all at once:

```
{{ form_row(form.emails) }}
```

A much more flexible method would look like this:

```
{{ form_label(form.emails) }}
{{ form_errors(form.emails) }}

<ul>
{% for emailField in form.emails %}
    <li>
        {{ form_errors(emailField) }}
        {{ form_widget(emailField) }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Please refer this documents for further details : https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html